# Why do we need to use double pointer to access a 2-D array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, double-pointer

I am trying to understand multidimensional array and pointers, wrote this small program to understand the concept:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void show(int arr[][2]);
int main()
{
    int z[2][2] = { { 1, 2 },
                    {3, 4 } };
    show(z);
}

void show(int arr[][2])
{

    printf("value of arr = %d", arr);
    printf("\n\nvalue of &arr[0]0] = %d", &arr[0][0]);
}
```

This code fragment prints the same address which makes sense, but when i edit the show function:

```
void show(int arr[][2])
{

    printf("value of *arr = %d", *arr);
    printf("\n\nvalue of arr[0]0] = %d", arr[0][0]);
}
```

*arr still prints the same address while the arr[0][0] as expected prints the integer value , i want to know why i need to use **arr to get the int value , if arr is storing the address it should be dereferenced with *arr, isn't it ?

please help i am having really hard time understanding this concept.. thanks in advance.

Comment: It'll help to stop thinking in terms of addresses. Pointers may be implemented in terms of memory addresses, but they aren't addresses, and thinking of them as addresses will mess you up in many more ways than just this one.

Comment: @user2357112 could you please refer me to some good text, where i  can understand this concept.

Comment: `*array_or_pointer` is same (type and value) as `array_or_pointer[0]` in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the memory layout of a 2D array, things might become a little bit clearer.

You have the variable defined as:

```
int z[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

Memory:

```
z
|
v
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Another view of the memory:

```
z[0]        z[1]
|           |
v           v
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Another view of the memory:

```
z[0][0]     z[1][0]
|   z[0][1] |    z[1][1]
|     |     |     |
v     v     v     v
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

You can now see that, as far as pure memory location is concerned,

```
&z == &z[0] == &z[0][0]
```

We also that know that when an array decays to a pointer, its value is the address of the first element of the array. Hence, when used in an expression that decays `z` to a pointer,

```
z == &z[0] == &z (from above)
```

It's puzzling but `z` and `&z` evaluate to the same address even though they are of different types.

Type of z when it decays to a pointer is `int (*)[2]`. The type of `&z` is `int (*)[2][2]`.

Coming to your function, you have:

```
void show(int arr[][2]) { ... }
```

That is equivalent to:

```
void show(int (*arr)[2]) { ... }
```

Why do `arr` and `*arr` evaluate to the same value?

`arr` evaluates to `&z[0]` from `main`.
`*arr` evaluates to `z[0]` from `main`, which evaluates to `&z[0][0]` from main.

We have already seen that value of `&z[0]` and `&z[0][0]` is the same. Hence `arr` and `*arr` in `show()` evaluate to the same address.

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks for the reply. it helped

Comment: @RSahu wow amazing unbelievably simple,correct and full of knowledge